# Extract multiple columns from matrix by column-name

Tags: r, select

I have got a `df` in `matrix`format and all the values inside are `numeric` (or `NA`). 
 An example of the `df`looks like this:

```
> dput(df)
structure(c(0, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 19.92053183, 19.94818362, 
19.97583542, 20.00348721, -0.846185488, -0.870922179, -0.895658869, 
-0.92039556, 56, 56, 56, 56, NA, 0.529513867, 0.477141211, 0.441261572, 
NA, NA, 32, 32), .Dim = c(4L, 7L), .Dimnames = list(c("A", "B", 
"C", "D"), c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G")))
```

I want to create a new matrix `df_new` from my `df` by selecting all rows and specific columns by name.

I tried:

1. `df_new = df[,c("A":"C","E","F":"G")]`
2. `df_new = select(df,"A":"C","E","F":"G")`
3. `df_new = select(df,c("A":"C","E","F":"G"))`

For the first code I get:

```
Error in "A":"C" : NA/NaN argument
In addition: Warning messages:
1: NAs introduced by coercion 
2: NAs introduced by coercion
```

For the second and third code I get:

```
Error in UseMethod("select_") : 
  no applicable method for 'select_' applied to an object of class "c('matrix', 'double', 'numeric')"
```

The result should look like this:

```
>df_new = df[,c("A":"C","E","F":"G")]
>df_new
 A B C E F G
A 1 NA 5 9 11 13
B 2 4 6 10 12 NA
C NA 5 NA NA 14
D 15 5 16 18 19
```

I think my mistake is something like a little typo-error, but I don't find it. Thanks in advance!

Comment: `"A":"C"` is not correct, perhaps try `dplyr::select(df, A:C, E, F:G)`? (More the point, `dplyr::select(mtcars, mpg:disp, wt, am:carb)` works for me. I don't have time to try to make your data since it does not read in correctly ... perhaps you can add the output from `dput(df)` to your question? It helps a lot!) BTW: this subsetting by column-range is unique to  `dplyr::select` and friends.)

Comment: Base R: `subset(mtcars, TRUE, c(mpg:disp, wt, am:carb))`

Comment: `dplyr::select`, which you are calling, does not work for matrices and your data seems to be of class `matrix`

Comment: Good point, perhaps I latched onto the use of `df` as a variable name (one I use frequently).

Comment: @r2evans I edited my post with a part from my original `df`. Yes I work with a `matrix` class `df`.

Comment: @Capt.Krusty thanks, that helps. Since it's a `matrix`, the functions from the `dplyr` package will not work for you. Luckily, `subset(df, TRUE, c(A:C, E))` works, as does `subset(df, TRUE, -D)`.

Comment: the `subset` function does the trick. Thanks. @r2evans Would you like to 'officially' answer the question, so I can accept your answer before deleting my question so you can get your reputation?

Comment: Don't delete the question, reps go away (I think) :-)

Comment: Its not possible to delete an answered question anyway ;)
Sadly some people downvoted my question already...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Up front: `dplyr::select` works on frames, not matrices. Fortunately, `subset` has an S3 method, `subset.matrix`:

```r
subset(df, TRUE, c(A:C, E))
#   A B        C  E
# A 0 1 19.92053 56
# B 1 2 19.94818 56
# C 2 3 19.97584 56
# D 3 4 20.00349 56
```

Alternatively, you can "subtract" columns as well.

```r
subset(df, TRUE, -D)
#   A B        C  E         F  G
# A 0 1 19.92053 56        NA NA
# B 1 2 19.94818 56 0.5295139 NA
# C 2 3 19.97584 56 0.4771412 32
# D 3 4 20.00349 56 0.4412616 32
```